# Is ther any other way to get sum 1 to 100 with recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm studing recursive function and i faced question of

"Print sum of 1 to n with no 'for' or 'while' "

ex ) n = 10

answer =
55

n = 100

answer = 5050

so i coded

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)

sum = 0
def count(n):
    global sum
    sum += n
    if n!=0:
        count(n-1)
count(n = int(input()))
print(sum)
```

I know it's not good way to get right answer, but there was a solution

```
n=int(input())

def f(x) :
    if x==1 :
        return 1
    else :
        return ((x+1)//2)*((x+1)//2)+f(x//2)*2

print(f(n))
```

and it works super well , but i really don't know how can human think that logic and i have no idea how it works.

Can you guys explain how does it works?
Even if i'm looking that formula but i don't know why he(or she) used like that
And i wonder there is another solution too (I think it's reall important to me)

I'm really noob of python and code so i need you guys help, thank you for watching this

Comment: According to Carl Friedrich Gauß: `print(((n ** 2) + n) // 2)` (explained [here](https://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/)).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution.

```py
def rsum(n):
    if n == 1: # BASE CASE
        return 1
    else: # RECURSIVE CASE
        return n + rsum(n-1)
```

You can also use `range` and `sum` to do so.

```py
n = 100
sum_1_to_n = sum(range(n+1))
```

Comment: OMG there was so beautiful way to get answer! Thank you for sharing your time to answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
def f(n):
   if n == 1:
       return 1
   return n + f(n - 1)

   print(f(10))
```

this function basically goes from n to 1 and each time it adds the current n, in the end, it returns the sum of n + n - 1 + ... + 1

Comment: Just a thought: What happens if you call f(0)?

Comment: I didn't consider this case, but you can simply add: "if n == 0: return 0"  or you can replace the "if n == 1: return 1" with "if n == 0: return 0"

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to find the answer

**1. Recursion**

```
def sum(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n + sum(n-1)
        
   
print(sum(100))
```

This is a simple recursion code snippet when you try to apply the recurrent function
F_n = n + F_(n-1) to find the answer

**2. Formula**

Let `S = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n`

Then let's do something like this

`S = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n`

`S = n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1`

Let's combine them and we get

`2S = (n + 1) + (n + 1) + ... + (n + 1)` - `n` times

From that you get

`S = ((n + 1) * n) / 2`

So for `n = 100`, you get

`S = 101 * 100 / 2 = 5050`

So in python, you will get something like

```
sum = lambda n: ( (n + 1) * n) / 2
        
   
print(sum(100))
```

Comment: Also avoid using built-in function names as your non-class function name

Comment: Checking for `n==1` is not required in your recursive function; just let it run through to adding 'sum(n-1)'

Comment: Please don't name a variable `sum`. This is already the name of a builtin function in python. Also, note that in python3, `/` returns a float, not an int. You want to return `(n * (n+1)) // 2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get at a recursive solution, you have to (re)define your problems in terms of finding the answer based on the result of a smaller version of the same problem.

In this case you can think of the result `sumUpTo(n)` as adding `n` to the result of `sumUpTo(n-1)`.  In other words:  `sumUpTo(n) = n + sumUpTo(n-1)`.

This only leaves the problem of finding a value of `n` for which you know the answer without relying on your `sumUpTo` function.  For example `sumUpTo(0) =  0`.  That is called your base condition.

Translating this to Python code, you get:

```
def sumUpTo(n): return 0 if n==0 else n + sumUpTo(n-1)
```

*Recursive solutions are often very elegant but require a different way of approaching problems.  All recursive solutions can be converted to non-recursive (aka iterative) and are generally slower than their iterative counterpart.*

The second solution is based on the formula `∑1..n = n*(n+1)/2`.  To understand this formula, take a number (let's say 7) and pair up the sequence up to that number in increasing order with the same sequence in decreasing order, then add up each pair:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  = 28
 7  6  5  4  3  2  1  = 28
-- -- -- -- -- -- --    --
 8  8  8  8  8  8  8  = 56
```

Every pair will add up to `n+1` (8 in this case) and you have `n` (7) of those pairs.  If you add them all up you get `n*(n+1)` = 56 which correspond to adding the sequence twice.  So the sum of the sequence is half of that total `n*(n+1)/2 = 28`.

The recursion in the second solution reduces the number of iterations but is a bit artificial as it serves only to compensate for the error introduced by propagating the integer division by 2 to each term instead of doing it on the result of `n*(n+1)`.  Obviously `n//2 * (n+1)//2` isn't the same as `n*(n+1)//2` since one of the terms will lose its remainder before the multiplication takes place.  But given that the formula to obtain the result mathematically is part of the solution doing more than 1 iteration is pointless.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me recursive function! I'll do my best to be a better programer!